# Stopping lightdm while trying to install nvidia driver ends-up to black screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lightdm

I get an error while trying to install the nvidia proprietary driver, which states that:

> you appear to be running an XServer.

So I've followed instruction provided [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1916961).

But when I enter

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

My screen goes completely blank and I am unable to proceed.

---

Running Ubuntu 16.04
Linux version 4.4.0-66-generic (buildd@lgw01-28) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)

Comment: You can (and should) install the recommended driver from the official repositories. And you can do that without typing a single line in terminal, just y opening Settings > Software Properties > Additional Drivers. It is not and never was recommended to install the Nvidia binaries directly although it is an option in a few special cases.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's always a good practice to only install and use tested and reliable drivers from Ubuntu repositories.

Here is what I would done If I wanted to install Nvidia proprietary driver.

As your question states, the driver is complaining about a running X server.

I ran the command you mentioned to stop `X`, and as you said I end-up with a black screen too, but when I pressed: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> I went to `tty2` and I was able to login and do my stuff without any running X Server.

So it seems when you stop `lightdm`, you are still at the `tty7` which graphical environment was running and it's not anymore, thats why you are getting a black screen. just change the `tty` with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or to <kbd>F6</kbd> and you will be good to go.

---

Anyway if you have some problems with that approach and it does not works for you, you can always kill the x:

```
pkill Xorg
```

*But let it for when nothing else works.*

---

You can also try the installation process by going into `multi-user.target` like:

```
sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

If you've got trouble with this one too (which is rare).

- Reboot your system
- When grub menu appears press e to edit the menu
- At the end of line which starts with linux add `systemd.unit=multi-user.target`
- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

Your system will bootup into multi-user target without a running X server. do your installation. then run:

```
sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

To run the graphical environment, or reboot the system if driver need it.

Answer (score 0):

The method described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/905218/527764) of stopping the lightdm service only worked for me the first time. I got blank screen in later update for some reason.

Finally I ssh into Ubuntu (16.04) and stopped lightdm. Then I was able to proceed to the installation.