# How to stop lightdm without getting dark?

Tags: nvidia, lightdm, services, cuda, console

I am trying to install on a freshly installed ubuntu  the drivers for my gtx1050.

At first it worked, I downloaded the display drivers for linux as a .run-file, I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> into a console and stopped the x-server by `service lightdm stop`. This worked perfectly and I could run the file.

But I still had no cuda drivers, so I downloaded the cuda toolkit 8.0 for linux and wanted to repeat the way, which worked with the display drivers. So I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> into a console and typed `service lightdm stop.` But this time it was different, it was pitch black and so I typed in the dark `service lightdm start` to see again.

### Well, I need to have the `lightdm` down in order to install the `cuda toolkit`, but i can't I am in the dark again as soon as I stop it.

NEWS:
So, systemctl isolate multi-user.target and service lightdm stop went full vin diesel riddick style pitch black on me, but after I ve uninstalled the display drivers both worked again, and this time I installed just the cuda-toolkit and it works fine, I guess the cuda-toolkit has also a display driver incorporated, and both display drivers did not come along well as two liberaces in one universe.

Comment: Have you tried pressing ctrl+alt+F1 when it's get darks? or ctrl+alt+F2? give it a shot works for me ;)

Comment: i first went into ctrl+alt+f1 and once I was there I did service lightdm stop. Though I tried the same with all consoles from ctrl+alt+f1 ..till.. ctrl+alt+F6

Comment: instead of stopping lightdm, run this: `sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target` install your stuff then run : `sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target` let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: at first, systemctl isolate multi-user.target also turned the screen into a dark chocolate bar, but after I ve uninstalled the display driver both the systemctl and service version worked perfectly.

Comment: So it should be the driver issue.... :/

Comment: yes, well i cant tell, since i do not know driver kung fu, but as a novice , i guess it is so .

Comment: see my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/905218/264781) might be helpful to you ;)